# Error incompatible types. Postfix evaluation

Tags: java, arrays, postfix-notation

My task is to create a program for postfix evaluation using array and char. 
I'm having trouble with the problem

> incompatible type: Object cannot be converted to int.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class StackPostfixEva { //class name
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in); //initialize scanner
    char[] postfix = new char[10]; //creating array

    System.out.println("Please enter postfix expression. Enter '#' if you have finish entering postfix expression ");  //instruction command
    int i; //initialize variable
    for (i = 0; i <= postfix.length; i++) { //loop for receiving input
      postfix[i] = key.next().charAt(i); //input command
      if (postfix[i] == '#') { //to indicate the end
        break;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("The postfix expression are:"); //to print postfix   
    expression
    for (i = 0; i <= postfix.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(postfix[i]);
    }
    Stack st = new Stack(); //creating stack
    int result, ch1, ch2; //initialize variable
    for (i = 0; i <= postfix.length; i++) { //loop for scanning each char
      if (postfix[i] >= '0' && postfix[i] <= '9') { //to determine operand
        st.push((int) postfix[i] - '0'); //push operand
      } 
      else 
      { //execution if operator found
        ch1 = st.pop(); //problem here
        ch2 = st.pop(); //problem here
        switch (postfix[1]) {
          case '+':
            result = ch2 + ch1;
            break;
          case '-':
            result = ch2 - ch1;
            break;
          case '*':
            result = ch2 * ch1;
            break;
          case '/':
            result = ch2 / ch1;
            break;
          case '%':
            result = ch2 / ch1;
            break;
          default:
            result = 0;
        } //end switch
        st.push(result);
      } //end else
    } //end for
    result = st.pop(); //problem here
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only using your stack to store `Integer` values, so I'd suggest specifying the generic type:

```
Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<>();
```

That way `st.pop()` will have type `Integer` and will be autoboxed to `int`.

When you just declare it as `Stack` (with no type parameters), `pop()` returns `Object` which is not convertible to `int` without an explicit cast (offered in another answer).

Comment: Thanks your solution work. But now I'm stuck with ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception. >.<

Comment: Done with the ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception but EmptyStack exception came right after.

Comment: You need to debug your code to see why a `pop()` operation is called on an empty stack. Any decent IDE (for example, IDEA, Eclipse, Netbeans) contains a debugger that allows to step through the code as it gets executed and see what happens with variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert it to integer.

```
ch1 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop());
ch2 = Integer.parseInt(st.pop());
```

Comment: This solution didn't work. It just give out the same error.